# How can I crash the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I was writing a system call, done that and its working correctly.
but I'm now looking for a way to crash the kernel somehow, and when does the kernel actually crash? I managed to put some pieces of code that would give me a few warnings and let the kernel compile correctly, but when does the actual crash occur?

Answer (score 2):

To cause a kernel panic "attack" =):

```
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: were you not asking how to trigger a kernel crash? From wikipedia: A kernel panic (sometimes abbreviated as KP[1]) is an action taken by an operating system upon detecting an internal fatal error from which it cannot safely recover. The term is largely specific to Unix and Unix-like systems

Comment: yes but I need some code or any instructions that would cause this.

Comment: execute the command above in a shell terminal and that's it... I didn't tried it, as I am right now working in the system.

Comment: I need to have it part of the system call that I write

Comment: In which language? c?

Comment: yes. thats how most kernel programming is done.

Comment: well... /proc/sysrq-trigger is a file. Just write a "c" char in it

Comment: Btw not working in Fedora23 4.4.4-301 , just tried it

Comment: In fedora at least, it's normally disabled by default at boot time. To re-enable it, edit /etc/sysctl.d/90-sysrq.conf and add the following line to it: kernel.sysrq = 1

Answer (score 1):

Give the credit to mmmint. Here is the c code. Should be run as root.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/proc/sysrq-trigger", "a");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "c");
    }
    printf("Are you running as root?");
}
```

and I know it works :-(

Comment: I didn't wanteed to test it...hehehe...By the way, you could also use the kernel function: void panic(const char *fmt, ...) http://linux.die.net/man/3/panic